# Easy way to do modulo for Date in PHP?

Tags: php

I have 28 unique events, one event per day. Events repeat after 28. is 1. event again.

Lets say first event is `1970-01-01`. Event 28 is `1970-01-28`.

Today is `2015-10-16`, how do I find out what event should be today? How do I find out what event should be for any given date? (just dates > `1970-01-01` and < `9999-12-31`).

I was thinking of converting `date` to `timestamp`, then do modulo 28*24*60*60, and then convert it back to `date`, but I'm afraid that there might be some margin. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `DateTime::diff` function as follow:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('1970-01-28');
$datetime2 = date_create('2015-10-16');
$interval = date_diff($datetime2, $datetime1);

/// Get total number of days
$days = $interval->format('%a');

/// Get the remainder of the division by the number of events
$eventNumber = $days % 28;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use unix timestamp to get date differences in terms of seconds. And since 01-01-1970 is zero by definition, all you have to do is:

```
$today = mktime(); // Or $today = mktime(12,0,0,10,16,2015);
$mod = floor($today/86400) % 28;
```